# Binding the DataContext of a UserControl in XAML is not working (Windows Phone)

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, mvvm

When I bind the `DataContext` of a `UserControl` the binding works correctly. When I debug the program, I can see that the `DataContext` of the `UserControl` is bound to the correct `ViewModel`. However, when I bind to specific properties (like a text box) in the `UserControl` to the `ViewModel`, something fails. The `UserControl` will pick up the initial values of the `ViewModel` correctly. If I have some binding string property with a default value of "test", the `UserControl` displays this correctly. However, none of the changes get propagated back to the `ViewModel`. So entering "abcd" into the textbox originally displaying "test" does not update the `ViewModel` to "abcd". The `ViewModel` incorrectly contains the "test" string.

If the above was unclear or not specific enough, continue on. I'll lay out my architecture with code and XAML snippets.

I have a VM that aggregates other VMs. In this parent VM, child VMs are exposed as a bindable property.

```
public class ParentViewModel : ViewModel
{
    #region Binding Properties

    private const string ChildViewModelPropertyName = "ChildViewModel";
    private ChildViewModel childViewModel = new ChildViewModel();
    public ChildViewModel ChildViewModel 
    {
        get { return this.childViewModel ; } 
        set
        {
            if (value == this.childViewModel )
            {
                return;
            }
            this.childViewModel = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(ChildViewModelPropertyName);
        }
    }

    //... 
}
```

The `ChildViewModel` is your typical VM and it exposes some other properties such as `Strings` that I want to bind to a text box or what not.

```
public class ChildViewModel : ViewModel
{
    #region Binding Properties

    private const string NamePropertyName = "Name";
    private string name = "";
    public string Name
    {
        get { return this.name; }
        set
        {
            if (value == this.name)
            {
                return;
            }
            this.name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(NamePropertyName);
        }
    }

    //...
}
```

Onto the XAML. The first XAML snippet represents an entire page, and this page's `DataContext` is bound to the `ParentViewModel`. This page contains a `UserControl` which has a `DataContext` binding associated with the `ChildViewModel` property exposed in the `ParentViewModel`.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage ...>

   <!-- Sets the DataContext for the page. -->
   <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.DataContext>
        <vm:ParentViewModel/>
   </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.DataContext>

   <ScrollViewer>
       <phone:Pivot>
           <phone:PivotItem>
               <!-- ChildView is the UserControl whose DataContext should be bound to ChildViewModel -->
               <view:ChildView DataContext="{Binding ChildViewModel}"/>
           </phone:PivotItem>
       </phone:Pivot>
   </ScrollViewer>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

The `ChildView` XAML is quite straight forward. There's a text box that is bound to the `Name` property in the `ChildViewModel`. To make it clear, I don't bind any `DataContext` in the `ChildView` since it has already been bound in the above snippet.

```
<UserControl ... >

    <StackPanel>
        <!-- Binding to the Name property -->
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    </StackPanel>

</UserControl>
```

If someone can tell me why this approach is not working, I will upvote your answer and say "Thanks!".

Comment: What can you see in the Output window at runtime ? Does it say there are some binding errors ?

Comment: No errors are reported. Just some messages of threads exiting and dll's being loaded.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the issue without success. Everything works fine for me. It's difficul to say what's going wrong in your app. Are you sure you never set the DataContext in code-behind ?

Comment: Thanks for trying to repro. The above is a simplified version of what is actually coded. I will scour through the code again. I must be missing something!

Comment: I've done more debugging, and the problem to me is clearer now. I will restate what I believe the problem is in the original question and include some more sample XAML with regards to the child view.

Comment: In summary, the `DataContext` for all `Views` is correct. So I was wrong initially, the `DataContext` bindings are working and are *not* being reset to the parent context. I confirmed this through more debugging and inspection... The issue I believe is with the communication between the `ChildView` and `ChildViewModel`, as the changes are not being propagated back to the `ChildViewModel` when something is changed in the `View`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<TextBox Text ="{Binding Name,
                Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Setting binding mode to `TwoWay` will let `View` to update `ViewModel`.

Comment: Doh! I thought TwoWay mode was default. Alas, it is not.